How to pass the referenced boardId to the createColumn function
I am making a trello like app with mern stack. Everything going smooth until I create a column. Postman says "Invalid board ID". When I hardcopy an existing boardID to the route the column is created
columnController
const createColumn = async (req, res) => {
  const { title } = req.body;
  const  boardId = req.params.boardId;
  
  const userId = req.user.userId;

  console.log('Received boardId:', boardId); // Debugging line
  console.log('Is boardId valid:', mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(boardId));

  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User not authenticated' });
  }

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(boardId)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid board ID' });
  }

  try {
    const newColumn = new Column({ title, user: userId, board: boardId });
    const column = await newColumn.save();
    res.status(201).json(column);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
  }
};

column model
const columnSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  board: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Board', required: true },

});

board model
const boardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});```


Can you share the output from console.log('Received boardId:', boardId); please? Also, which version of mongoose are you using? You should look at mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString() as a better alternative.
